# Pass a value from presentviewcontroller to a viewcontroller by didSelect method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, pass-data

```
  comp_noti *ab=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CompNoti"];

  ab.cfid=@"b";

  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

I am using the above method but, I don't get the value b in the viewcontroller.

Comment: use [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:NULL]; to dismissViewControllerAnimated

Comment: You can't pass value using `dismissViewControllerAnimated`

Comment: Thank you sir for your support.

Answer (score 2):

in AppDelegate.h create Property Like Below :

```
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *cfid;
```

and in AppDelegate.m `@synthesize`  like Below :

```
@synthesize cfid;
```

and after that when you set value on `cfid` in  `presentViewController` set AppDelegate instance like Below :

```
import AppDelegate.h
```

and create instance in `viewDidLoad` like Below :

```
 AppDelegate *app=(AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```

and after that set your code in question below like that :

```
comp_noti *ab=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CompNoti"];

  app.cfid=@"b";

  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

now you get anywhere value **cfid** just create `AppDelegate` instance. i hope it will help you.

Comment: if problem solved in one line than why use appdelegate variable

Comment: @Jigar please read question Properly, if you answer in one line then give answer it's important for me and also the question owner

Comment: Thank you . This is method also i am used and it work correctly Thank you for your support

Comment: @Nilesh you dont know how can pass data using presentviewcontroller and navigationcontroller

Comment: @Jigar i know very well, but regarding to question this is the correct way. to get a value from anywhere.and also question owner solved the problem.so just chill.

Answer (score 1):

```
comp_noti *ab=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CompNoti"];

ab.cfid=@"b";

[self.navigationController pushViewController:ab animated:true]
```

Comment: from **presentviewcontroller** you can not push a viewcontroller.